# In CommCare, which date case property references the date the case was created?

Tags: commcare

I want to close a case in a CommCare application (app built on CommCare opensource platform), and I would like to do so by creating a rule that references the date the case was opened. However when I look at an export of case data, I see two possible case properties, one in the export and one in the case list configuration drop down on CommCare HQ that could refer to case closure. I'm sure others have been confused by this: One case property is called "opened_date"(in the export), whereas in a case list configuration dropdown on CommCareHQ, the case property is "date-opened". Which one should I use when I create a rule for case closure based on the date the case was opened? I've checked the online commcare public confluence documentation but couldn't figure out which one to use.

Comment: I've made changes to clarify this question. Can whomever closed clarify what exactly they think is unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to add onto Ben's answer - CommCare and CommCare HQ have different representations of the case data which is why this is confusing. The case closure rules rely on CommCare HQ's representation which is why you would use `opened_on`. Unfortunately I don't think there is any easy way to view that format on CommCare HQ, but if you are technically minded you can inspect the [source code](https://github.com/dimagi/commcare-hq/blob/master/corehq/ex-submodules/casexml/apps/case/models.py#L153). Mobile's representation, on the other hand, is [much better documented](https://github.com/dimagi/commcare-core/wiki/casedb).

Answer (score 3):

Confusingly enough, the proper way to access the opened date of a case in a form is to use the `opened_on` property. Both `opened_date` and `date-opened` are aliases for the `opened_on` property.